# An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_updateextendedproperty'

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am getting this error while updating Column Comments for several tables. Surprisingly query is running fine if I run them separately but when I consolidate all execute statement in single statement then I Get above error.

Below is syntax, there is no issue in syntax all queries are running fine separately only issue occur I  run them together.

```
EXEC sp_updateExtendedProperty @name = N'MS_Description'
,@value = N'Month ID LIKE (YYYYMM)'
,@level0type = N'SCHEMA'
,@level0name = N'dbo'
,@level1type = N'TABLE'
,@level1name = N'HHSI_OPRTN_APP_DY_FCT'
,@level2type = N'COLUMN'
,@level2name = N'MO_ID'
 GO
```

Comment: Add the code that shows the error when you run them together.

Comment: Do any of the values in the problem query contain single quotes ('), e.g. `@value = N'Product's length'`?

Comment: This error can appear when the @name parameter is NULL.

Comment: I found the issue, was very silly mistake it was huge set of sql  and some where in middle for one of the column I passed SchemUpdate instead of SCHEMA in @level0type parameter. I was not able to troubleshoot before because SQL server was showing error on some different line where every thing was fine.